# Mongoose operation to count by date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a large amount of time series data that I would like to get counts of by each day.

For instance, say I'd like to query a date range from 3 days to ago to now. Say there are 1000 errors 3 days ago, 2000 errors 2 days ago, and 500 today. My objects have a 'created' date field.

For this I could do

```
MyModel.count( { created: { $gte: threeDaysAgo, $lte: today } })
```

and then repeat for the other two days. This becomes an issue when the user wants to search for a span of 300 days - I'd have to do 300 operations. So I'd like to skip individual queries.

Is there a Mongoose / MongoDB operation that will return these sums to me without having to do an individual call for each day?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could query 3 days and select for the created date, then compute your counts on the result.

Comment: Thanks Jim, hadn't thought of that. A little worried about the performance though - there may be 200,000+ objects being returned. But I suppose just selecting the created field would improve performance.

Comment: If it's too many, three "count" transactions might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with aggregation. Here's my code:

```
             DBLogData.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { application: application.id }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                           day: {
                              $dayOfMonth: "$created"
                          },
                          month: {
                              $month: "$created"
                          },
                          year: {
                              $year: "$created"
                          }
                      },
                        count: {
                            $sum: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ], (error, graphCountDatas) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    callback(null, graphCountDatas);
                }
            });
```

And some references:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/aggregation/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation-date/